# Laravel test unitario de ruta pública existente siempre falla - 404

Tags: laravel, phpunit

Tengo el un test unitario en Laravel 7.28.4 / PHPUnit 8.5.8, en Ubuntu / Apache
que me esta fallando, siempre devuelve 404, la ruta es pública y funciona en el navegador.

La salida para PHPUnit:

```
Expected status code 200 but received 404.
Failed asserting that 200 is identical to 404.
```

He ejecutado con `php ./vendor/bin/phpunit` y `php artisan test`, en el segundo caso en algun momento he tenido este resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La clase con el test:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Shop;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Tests\TestCase;

class ProductsControllerTest extends TestCase
{
    use DatabaseMigrations, RefreshDatabase;

    public function testShopRoute()
    {
        $response = $this->get(route('shop'));
        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }

    public function testProductRoute()
    {
        $url = route('shop-product', ['no-exists', 1]);
        $this->get($url)->assertStatus(404);

        //$url = route('shop-product', ['colgante-maduli', 1]);
        $url = 'http://www.mu-cms.local/tienda-online/producto/colgante-maduli/1';
        //$url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/tienda-online/producto/colgante-maduli/1'; // php artisan serve
        $this->get($url)->assertStatus(200);
    }
}
```

`testShopRoute()` pasa sin problemas.

En mi *.env* tengo:

```
APP_ENV=test
APP_URL=http://www.mu-cms.local/
```

Mi fichero "phpunit.xml":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit.xsd"
    bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
    colors="true"
>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Unit">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Unit</directory>
        </testsuite>
        <testsuite name="Feature">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Feature</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <filter>
        <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
            <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
    <php>
        <server name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <server name="BCRYPT_ROUNDS" value="4"/>
        <server name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <server name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>
        <server name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/>
        <server name="MAIL_MAILER" value="array"/>
        <server name="QUEUE_CONNECTION" value="sync"/>
        <server name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <server name="TELESCOPE_ENABLED" value="false"/>
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

He probado varias propuestas de este hilo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47381597/laravel-phpunit-returns-404

- Ejecutar: `php artisan config:cache`
- Añadí:

  processIsolation="true"
  stopOnFailure="false"

en el fichero de configuración de PHPUnit.

He probado a eliminar las consultas a la BD de la ecuación en el controlador devolviendo sólo la vista y continua fallando.

**¿Puede ser un problema con mi *PHPUnit* o algo que estoy haciendo mal con los test?**

> Editado

Ya esta solucionado. Sigo sin saber que causo el error o como se ha resuelto...

Un apunte, el valor correcto en el fichero .env *APP_ENV* es *testing*: `APP_ENV=testing`, limpie cache después corregirlo y los test pasarón, volví atrás para comprobar si era esto, es decir puse un valor incorrecto y volví a limpiar cache y seguían pasando...

Comment: Es correcta la forma que pasas una variable a tu ruta? ['variable', 1] no debería ser ['variable' => valor]?

Comment: @L.Flor en la doc, se indica como dices. Yo suelo hacerlo de la otra forma, solo hay que tener cuidado del orden... Se genera la misma URL: por ejemplo: `dd(route('shop-product', ['slug'=>'colgante-maduli', 'id'=>1]), route('shop-product', ['colgante-maduli', 1]));` imprime dos URLs idénticas. En mi caso no importa, porque he usado la ruta cogida directamente del navegador, donde si funciona, y no resuelve mi problema.